# Comparing multiple strings to list of regular expressions C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I am trying to compare multiple strings to a list of regular expressions.  I am trying to make it so i can compare all the strings i have to all of the regular expressions and if it DOESNT match any of the regular expressions then it gets put into a list so i know it doesnt match. My method works when i have only 1 regular expression but does completely quits working when i add 2 or more.

```
public List<string> CheckNames(List<string> nameList, List<string> regexList)
    {
        var missMatchNameList = new List<string>();
        foreach (var name in nameList)
        {
          foreach(var regex in regexList)
          {
                if (!Regex.IsMatch(name, regex))
                {
                    missMatchNameList.Add(name);
                    break;
                }  
          }        
        } 
        return missMatchNameList;
    }
```

that is my code so far, what am i missing here?? Any tips would be great!

Comment: Remove the `break;`?

Comment: @SebastianHofmann unfortunately i have tried that and it has not worked.

Comment: Instead of saying “completely quits working” show us what you pass to `CheckNames`, what it returns, and what you expected it to return.

Comment: Just a thought. If you don't care which regex it matches against, why not concatenate your regex list into one long regex with ORs then just match against that one regex rather than you performing the loop?

Comment: it looks valid to me...and answers below look logically equivalent...one of hit an invalid one...you dont need to check the rest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
  public List<string> CheckNames(List<string> nameList, List<string> regexList)
        {
            var missMatchNameList = new List<string>();
            foreach (var name in nameList)
            {
              var matched = false;
              foreach(var regex in regexList)
              {
                 if (Regex.IsMatch(name, regex))
                 {
                   matched=true;
                   break; 
                 }  
              }  
                 if (!matched)
                 {
                     missMatchNameList.Add(name);
                 }  
            } 
            return missMatchNameList;

        }
```

this issue because you break when not matching with first regex so you don't compare the remaining regexs

Comment: Did you really just update your answer with the same comment as me, and then add the break statement in, because I find it hard to believe you're psychic!

Comment: I didn't see you code I just enhance my code to not compare all remaining regexs

Answer (score 2):

Change this

```
foreach (var name in nameList)
    {
      foreach(var regex in regexList)
      {
            if (!Regex.IsMatch(name, regex))
            {
                missMatchNameList.Add(name);
                break;
            }  
      }        
    }
```

To

```
foreach (var name in nameList)
    {
      bool match = false;
      foreach(var regex in regexList)
      {
            if (Regex.IsMatch(name, regex))
            {
                match = true;                  
                break;
            }  
      }
      if (!match)
          missMatchNameList.Add(name);
    }
```

Your problem was that as soon one of you regex expressions didn't match, it got added to the list, even if it matched another regex.

Also, by keeping the `break;` you don't carry on processing all the other regexs after you find a match.

Comment: I think the `if` statement should look like `if (match == false)`, or `if (!match)`...

Comment: Updated! Thanks for the feedback ;0)